# Implode array with null keyword

Tags: javascript

I have following array like below

```
[1,null,null,2]
```

I want to implode make it as string like below

```
1,null,null,2
```

I tried

```
temparr.join(',')
```

But I am getting

```
1,,,2
```

How do i preserve the keyword null.

Comment: By replacing it with the _text value_ `null` first? Or by writing your own join function, that takes your special requirement into account.

Answer (score 4):

You could convert the values to string in advance, because `undefined` or `null` values are empty string by converting with [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join#description).

> If an element is `undefined`, `null` or an empty array `[]`, it is converted to an empty string.

```js
const array = [1, null, null, 2];

console.log(array.map(String).join(','));
```

Answer (score 1):

Map to a string first:

```js
[1,null,null,2].map(String).join(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make `join` do that, so you would have to change the input given to `join` in the first place. For example:

```js
const result = [1, null, null, 2].map(value => value === null ? "null" : value).join(",");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the **value** `null` by the **string** `'null'` :

```js
console.log([1,null,null,2].map(x => x ?? 'null').join(','))
```